`docker compose watch` hot reload feature is not working
So i followed the "Develop with Containers" tutorial section on the official docker website (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/introduction/develop-with-containers/) and tried to make changes to the code to see if the changes are reflected on the browser. However, the changes are not being reflected unless i restart the container with docker compose watch. You may check out the video below to see what i mean.
Things to note:

I did not make any changes to the Dockerfile nor to the compose.yml file.
I only made changes to the frontend (like changing the colour) and the backend (changing the greeting title)
All i did was cloned the repository and run docker compose watch

What i have tried:

clone again the repo and started again using docker compose watch
deleted the containers and images and try to re-run it again with docker compose watch`
also tried running docker compose up --watch, issue still persists.

About my system (if its relevant):
Macbook Air M3
